# Finding the first non blank cell and return that value and adjacent cell's value

Tags: excel, formula

Hi I am using Excel 2013. 
I have a formula (in Cell F14) to retrieve the first non blank from a range of cells in column B ( Range B8:B12).

```
=INDEX(B8:B12,MATCH(1,IF(B8:B12<>0,IF(B8:B12<>"",1)),0))
```

That is an array formula so needs to use ctrl+shift+enter.

Now I want to retrieve the data that is adjacent (Column A) to the first blank cell and put it in Cell F15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On f15 enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F14,B:B,0))
```

Usually you can use `Match` and `Index` when the cell you want to find is not in the left most column. otherwise a simple `vlookup` can do the job.